# Why do I get 'The expected product version was not found' when applying cumulative upgrade?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to perform a long overdue update on our test SharePoint 2010 server.

I have managed to install SP2 (German) for both Foundation and Portal server. Also the Foundation Cumulative Upgrade (Aug15) was installed sucessfully.

When I try to install the Portal Server CU (Aug15) I get an error message

> The expected product version was not found

and the installation
aborts.

I can only see the SP2 as a prerequisite and that installed successfully. How can I find out more information on what exactly was expected?

The installation files are:

*Foundation:*

```
wsssp2010-kb2687464-fullfile-x64-de-de & wssloc2010-kb3055049-fullfile-x64-glb
```

*Portal server:*

```
oserversp2010-kb2687453-fullfile-x64-de-de & ubersrv2010-kb3055040-fullfile-x64-glb
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling from the command line with the parameter ´PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1´ allowed the installation process to continue. I don't know what side-effects it might have...

```
ubersrv2010-kb3055040-fullfile-x64-glb PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1
```